# How to add custom css in magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2.2

I am a new to magento forntend devloper i tried search for this solution i am not getting any solution. This is my custom theme folder structure in **Magento 2.2.2** i saved `default_header_html.xml` file in the following way in layout folder..

> app/design/frontend/custom-theme/my-first-theme/view/layout/default_header_html.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:view/layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <css src="../../web/css/abc.css"/>
        </head>
    </page>
```

My css folder path

> app/design/frontend/custom-theme/my-first-theme/web/css/abc.css

using above xml file i tried to access abc.css file but not working. Can u please help me for accessing my abc.css file

Answer (score 0):

> change

```
<css src="../../web/css/abc.css"/>
```

> to

```
<css src="css/filename.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file path is Wrong.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_header_html.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/filename.css" />
        <script src="js/filename.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Put your **JS** and **CSS** file in below path.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/filename.css
>   app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/js/filename.css

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file or copy it from parent theme to

> app/design/frontend/custom-theme/my-first-theme/Magento_Theme/view/layout/default_header_html.xml

inside this file add entry to your css file as

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/abc.css" />
  </head>
</page>
```

Finally, add your abc.css file to the web/css folder of your my-first-theme

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for gave me answer  i got css file in pub>static>frontend>custom-theme>my-first-theme>en_US>css>abc.css. But the abc.css link was not showing in web browser